# Could not build module 'NUI': 'NUIParse/NUIParse.h' file not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, objective-c-swift-bridge

There is a problem with importing the NUI pod inside `Swift-Bridging-Header.h`. NUI module can't be built because of a missing dependency `<NUIParse/NUIParse.h>`.

- I even tried adding `NUIParse` into the `Podfile`, but it didn't
  help.
- `pod install` doesn't help either

The problem appears to be the non-module import of `<NUIParse/NUIParse.h>` inside `NUI` Pod module, how to avoid the problem?

Part of the `Podfile`, where `NUI` is defined:

> pod 'NUI', :git => 'https://github.com/peantunes/nui.git'

Compilation error in Xcode console:

```
/Users/user/ReactProject/ios/ReactProject/Swift-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: note: while building module 'NUI' imported from /Users/user/ReactProject/ios/ReactProject/Swift-Bridging-Header.h:7:
#import <NUI/NUISettings.h>
        ^
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "Headers/NUI-umbrella.h"
        ^
/Users/user/ReactProject/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NUI/NUI.framework/Headers/NUI-umbrella.h:13:9: note: in file included from /Users/user/ReactProject/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NUI/NUI.framework/Headers/NUI-umbrella.h:13:
#import "NUIDeclaration.h"
        ^
/Users/user/ReactProject/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NUI/NUI.framework/Headers/NUIDeclaration.h:10:9: error: 'NUIParse/NUIParse.h' file not found
#import "NUIParse/NUIParse.h"
        ^
/Users/user/ReactProject/ios/ReactProject/Swift-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: error: could not build module 'NUI'
#import <NUI/NUISettings.h>
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/user/ReactProject/ios/ReactProject/Swift-Bridging-Header.h'
```

`Swift-Bridging-Header.h`:

```
#import <NUI/NUISettings.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

`NUIDeclaration.h` within the `NUI` module:

```
#import <NUIParse/NUIParse.h>

@interface NUIDeclaration : NSObject<NUIPParseResult>

@property (strong) NSString *property;
@property (strong) NSString *value;

@end
```